# iOS Best Practice - Updating an object in parent view's collection

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I want to know your opinions on what is the best way to do this.

I have a view controller (EventsController) with a UITableView. It fetches events data from a backend app and stores them in an instance variable events (NSArray). It uses the events array to populate the table view.

When a user taps on one of the rows in the table, they are taken to another view controller (EventDetailController). During the segue, EventDetailController is passed the selected event object. 
The detail controller lets the user follow or unfollow this event. When the user follows / unfollows an event that information is sent to the backend. At present after the a successful response is received from the backend, the detail controller posts a notification letting observers know that events were changed. 
EventsController observes this notification and when it gets the notification, reloads itself (fetches all events from backend and reloads the table). I think this is excessive (btw, this notification is used by a view other than EventsController as well, I think that is why they went with notifications instead of protocol / delegate).

My question is regarding how to update the changed event in EventsController without going to the backend. 
Note that both controllers are inside of a Navigation Controller.

1. During segue pass the selected event object to the detail controller
   as isbeing done now. The detail controller upon successful response
   from backend updates this very event object. So in effect the object
   in events array in EventsController will be updated.
   EventsController  can trigger a reload of the table in
   viewWillAppear and so the change will be reflected when user
   navigates back to EventsController.
2. Using protocol / delegate method let the EventsController know that
   event was followed or unfollowed.

   - a. In EventsController when protocol method is called, find the event (they have unique id
     properties) in the array, update it and reload table.
   - b. Or in EventsController maintain not only an array of events but also a
     dictionary (key will be event id and value will be index of that
     object in the events array) protocol method is called, it can look
     up find the event more quickly in the array and update it. And call
     reload table.

Which would you use the current method, 1, 2.a or 2.b? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate Events out into a model class.  You can instantiate it in EventsController and pass it down into EventDetailController via a property, or you can make it a singleton that the entire app has access to.  When you change an event in the event detail, just update it in your EventModel class, and have the model class broadcast the notification, or just observe the events array via KVO.  (Just a word of warning: If you use a mutable array for the events array, mutating one object in the collection will NOT trigger a KVO notification. You have to replace the array to get the automatic note.)

Once you separate out the model this way you will find it very easy to do things like reload from a network service, save events, modify events, etc from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Ah thats an excellent solution. When you say model, you don't necessarily mean core data, do you? The model can be a singleton with an array that represents all events? And the EventsController can just pass the selected events index to the detail controller.

Comment: Don't need core data for this. Just a class with an array of events that you can modify/observe as needed.